# Will upgrading of windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 results in loss of data

Tags: windows, installation, operating-system

I have installed operating system windows server 2003 on my PC. I have installed some additional softwares like visual studio 2010, sql server 2008 & MOSS 2007 on windows server 2003. Now I want to upgrade my windows server 2003 with the new operating system windows server 2008. I am not aware about the whether upgrade will loose data stored on hard drive or will it loose data from program file ( means it will loose the installation of the softwares visual studio 2010, sql server 2008, MOSS 2007). Please tell me whether I will loose the installation of the software programs such as visual studio 2010, sql server 2008, MOSS 2008 or not after upgrading the windows server 2003 to windows server 2008?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally the purpose of the upgrade it prevent any data loss, however with Microsoft you never know.